# Error with integration test

Tags: integration-test, magento2.3

After a fresh install of the latest beta Magento release, I have an error when running integration tests that seems to be related to stock feature. Since the stock has been under heavy development in this release, I was wondering if anybody knows how to resolve this one?

After fresh install of Magento 2.3 with sample data, the integration test command `php ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit` returns an error, see below:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento23_test.inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `e`.*, `selection`.*, `stock_status_index`.`is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

Answer (score 9):

The CREATE ALGORITHM statement requires elevated MySQL access.  It is likely that the server you are working on does not have this and will halt the import process.

This line needs to come out of the SQL being migrated.

Instead run the following to create the view

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Answer (score 3):

its because inventory_stock_1 view is dropped
execute this query on your database for magento 2.3

dont forget to replace replace PUT_YOUR_DATABASE_USER_NAME_HERE

```
--
-- Structure for view `inventory_stock_1`
--

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`PUT_YOUR_DATABASE_USER_NAME_HERE`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on(`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)) ;

--
-- VIEW  `inventory_stock_1`
-- Data: None
--
```

Comment: I know I got this resolved at the time but I admit I lost track with what was the issue. Apologies I can’t recall whether your solution would resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this SQL query to resolve your issue

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Comment: No this is not working for me