# Magento Admin Order Grid Not Loading

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I try to access the Admin **order grid** it gives something went wrong error message.

When I opened the Excetion log I have the below

> [2019-04-26 13:23:24] report.CRITICAL: The stock item with the "2074"
>   ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The
>   stock item with the \"2074\" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try
>   again. at
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:200)"}
>   []

Can anyone help fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate the database using mysql dump? In 2.3 they introduced a mysql view (virtual table) for stock and I've seen similar errors if this is not created properly.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263317/70343