# Magento 2: Products Aren't Showing up. But they exist in backend!

Tags: magento2, product, category-products

I've added products in the backend even a test one. But they will not show up no matter what we do.

We have already tried `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` in the SSH
We have cleared the cache, It worked on the local build but once we pushed it up it just refused to work. All the products have been manually added.

Im pulling my hair out at the moment.

They are visible in backend, But not in frontend, I cant see them in the products menu.

Does anyone have any ideas what on earth is going on?

I've editing the following files:
**app\code\Modules\Catalog\etc\di.xml** **app\code\Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full.php**

As referenced in this stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927658/products-is-not-showing-up-on-magento2-subcategory#answer-44364827

We have also tried invalidating and then reindexing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

> EDIT!

We decided to see if we could view the product its self by going to its direct url and we got an `inventory_stoc_1` Error

Comment: Checked visibility and status on both top level scope and individual store scope?  Also how did you add products? Through manual add process via backend?

Comment: @DominicXigen We Added manually in the back end, Then they got overwritten by upload Later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! :)

Refrence this awnser: [Error with integration test](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249286/error-with-integration-test?rq=1#answer-263317)

We applied the following code into the SQL:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Thank you for any help. Problem is now solved.

Comment: Ha! I was just about suggest using my answer in the stack overflow link :)  It's the MSI https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/ feature new to 2.3